# Can we integrate chrome dev tools to any IDE or any HTML editor

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, google-chrome-devtools

I need integrate remote debugging capability to my development environment. Chrome dev tools in one of best remote debugger that we can use. So can we integrate it directly to any IDE that we can use??

Please help if anybody have some thing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Btw, I found this article from web,

 - http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/debug-javascript-eclipse

Comment: If IDE is extendable you can use [remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) to integrate it with Chrome.